# Logs not showing up when running JAR as a service

Tags: java, linux, service, jar, daemon

I have a fat JAR ([Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)) that if I start using `java -jar filename.jar` creates two log files: one application log (that's usually stdout) and another one that creates an entry each time the webserver is hit.

Now when I start this as a service with a file in */etc/init.d/* (see snippet below) I don't get any log files created (other than */opt/service-name/log* that only shows stdout before the application starts). It's not a permission issue - I tried starting the service with a user that doesn't have permissions and it doesn't start. And I tried `find / logfile.log` with no luck.

```
daemon --user=root --pidfile=/var/run/service-name.pid java -jar /opt/service-name/filename.jar > /opt/service-name/log 2>&1 & echo $!
```

Any ideas why the log files are not being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I set the application to specifically log to `/var/log/service-name/` logs do get written. Still unsure why, will update if I find out.

Comment: if its not a permissions issue, then certainly it has to be working directory issue. Did you specify the working directory in your service definition like: `WorkingDirectory=/path/to/working/director`

Answer (score 1):

Try to first redirect stderr to stdout, and then redirect stdout to file, e.g.

```
daemon --user=root --pidfile=/var/run/service-name.pid java -jar /opt/service-name/filename.jar 2>&1 >/opt/service-name/log & echo $!
```

Also, the `& echo $!` part looks suspicious to me. If I read [specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03_02) correctly, a single `&` may result in `echo $!` returning before daemon has returned, which means you will get a wrong pid. Do you want to run `&& echo $!` or perhaps `; echo $!` instead?

Comment: No luck with the logs yet, but +1 on the `&& echo $!`

Comment: Right, the [manpage](http://libslack.org/daemon/manpages/daemon.1.html) suggests that you pass the logfile name via `-O` argument to daemon. In hindsight, it makes sense, because you don't want to redirect output from daemon, which exits. Instead, you want daemon to wire your program's stdout to file when it starts the subprocess.